# What is the harmonic content of a PWM signal?

Tags: pwm, filter, harmonics, distortion

Suppose I'm using a 3.6 kHz carrier to reproduce a 60 Hz sine wave. To properly design a filter for this application to hit a specific harmonic distortion target, I need to know the harmonic content of the PWM signal. How can I predict what that harmonic content is? Is it going to vary dramatically with the pulse widths? Or will there be certain simplifying assumptions I can make?

Comment: 60Hz + the Fourier series of a square wave with a fundamental of 3.6kHz

Comment: PWM is just a series of pulses. Rectangular pulse function is represented by the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) in the Fourier domain. So it has an infinite number of harmonics. The "narrower" is the pulse, the wider is the `sinc`.

Comment: Aww, fudge.  I was thinking of the resulting harmonics on the 60Hz signal, not the harmonics content of the PWM.   I've deleted my other comment.

Comment: Stephen, are you done with this Q and A now? If not, please leave a comment explaining your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 50:50 mark space ratio you are dealing with a square wave and this should be a good start (this is for a 1kHz square wave): -

[image]

When it comes to other duty cycles try this for size: -

[image]

Presumably your filter might be a 2nd order low-pass type made from L and C. Keep the resonant point at least 50% above 60Hz to prevent catestrophic series resonance at 60Hz. You can easily simulate this to see what current this filter might be taking an an unloaded 60Hz supply and I would recommend simulation to furnish you with the total harmonic distortion.